# Placement-new vs gcc 4.4.3 strict-aliasing rules

Tags: c++, gcc, placement-new, pointer-aliasing, type-punning

I've got some code that I've been using successfully for some years to implement a "variant-type object"; that is, a C++ object that can hold a values of various types, but only uses (approximately) as much memory as the largest of the possible types.  The code is similar in spirit to a tagged-union, except that it supports non-POD data types as well.  It accomplishes this magic by using a char buffer, placement new/delete, and reinterpret_cast<>.

I recently tried compiling this code under gcc 4.4.3 (with -O3 and -Wall), and got lots of warnings like this:

```
warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules
```

From what I've read, this is an indication that the gcc's new optimizer might generate 'buggy' code, which I obviously would like to avoid.

I've pasted a 'toy version' of my code below; is there anything I can do to my code to make it safer under gcc 4.4.3, while still supporting non-POD data types?  I know that as a last resort I could always compile the code with -fno-strict-aliasing, but it would be nice to have code that doesn't break under optimization so I'd rather not do that.

(Note that I'd like to avoid introducing a boost or C++0X dependency into the codebase, so while boost/C++0X solutions are interesting, I'd prefer something a little more old-fashioned)

```
#include <new>

class Duck
{
public:
   Duck() : _speed(0.0f), _quacking(false) {/* empty */}
   virtual ~Duck() {/* empty */}  // virtual only to demonstrate that this may not be a POD type

   float _speed;
   bool _quacking;
};

class Soup
{
public:
   Soup() : _size(0), _temperature(0.0f) {/* empty */}
   virtual ~Soup() {/* empty */}  // virtual only to demonstrate that this may not be a POD type

   int _size;
   float _temperature;
};

enum {
   TYPE_UNSET = 0,
   TYPE_DUCK,
   TYPE_SOUP
};

/** Tagged-union style variant class, can hold either one Duck or one Soup, but not both at once. */
class DuckOrSoup
{
public:
   DuckOrSoup() : _type(TYPE_UNSET) {/* empty*/}
   ~DuckOrSoup() {Unset();}

   void Unset() {ChangeType(TYPE_UNSET);}
   void SetValueDuck(const Duck & duck) {ChangeType(TYPE_DUCK); reinterpret_cast<Duck*>(_data)[0] = duck;}
   void SetValueSoup(const Soup & soup) {ChangeType(TYPE_SOUP); reinterpret_cast<Soup*>(_data)[0] = soup;}

private:
   void ChangeType(int newType);

   template <int S1, int S2> struct _maxx {enum {sz = (S1>S2)?S1:S2};};
   #define compile_time_max(a,b) (_maxx< (a), (b) >::sz)
   enum {STORAGE_SIZE = compile_time_max(sizeof(Duck), sizeof(Soup))};

   char _data[STORAGE_SIZE];
   int _type;   // a TYPE_* indicating what type of data we currently hold
};

void DuckOrSoup :: ChangeType(int newType)
{
   if (newType != _type)
   {
      switch(_type)
      {
         case TYPE_DUCK: (reinterpret_cast<Duck*>(_data))->~Duck(); break;
         case TYPE_SOUP: (reinterpret_cast<Soup*>(_data))->~Soup(); break;
      }
      _type = newType;
      switch(_type)
      {
         case TYPE_DUCK: (void) new (_data) Duck();  break;
         case TYPE_SOUP: (void) new (_data) Soup();  break;
      }
   }
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   DuckOrSoup dos;
   dos.SetValueDuck(Duck());
   dos.SetValueSoup(Soup());
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you submitted this code to the GCC team, maybe as a bug report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, you can do it if you are willing to store an extra void *.  I reformatted your sample a bit so it was easier for me to work with.  Look at this and see if it fits your needs.  Also, note that I provided a few samples so you can add some templates to it that will help usability.  They can be extended much more, but that should give you a good idea.

There is also some output stuff to help you see what is going on.

One more thing, I assume you know that you need to provide appropriate copy-ctor and assignment-operator but that is not the crux of this problem.

My g++ version info:

> g++ --version
>   g++ (SUSE Linux) 4.5.0 20100604 [gcc-4_5-branch revision 160292]

```
#include <new>
#include <iostream>

class Duck
{
public:
   Duck(float s = 0.0f, bool q = false) : _speed(s), _quacking(q)
  {
    std::cout << "Duck::Duck()" << std::endl;
  }
   virtual ~Duck() // virtual only to demonstrate that this may not be a POD type
   {
     std::cout << "Duck::~Duck()" << std::endl;
   }

   float _speed;
   bool _quacking;
};

class Soup
{
public:
   Soup(int s = 0, float t = 0.0f) : _size(s), _temperature(t)
  {
    std::cout << "Soup::Soup()" << std::endl;
  }
   virtual ~Soup() // virtual only to demonstrate that this may not be a POD type
   {
     std::cout << "Soup::~Soup()" << std::endl;
   }

   int _size;
   float _temperature;
};

enum TypeEnum {
   TYPE_UNSET = 0,
   TYPE_DUCK,
   TYPE_SOUP
};
template < class T > TypeEnum type_enum_for();
template < > TypeEnum type_enum_for< Duck >() { return TYPE_DUCK; }
template < > TypeEnum type_enum_for< Soup >() { return TYPE_SOUP; }

/** Tagged-union style variant class, can hold either one Duck or one Soup, but not both at once. */
class DuckOrSoup
{
public:
   DuckOrSoup() : _type(TYPE_UNSET), _data_ptr(_data) {/* empty*/}
   ~DuckOrSoup() {Unset();}

   void Unset() {ChangeType(TYPE_UNSET);}
   void SetValueDuck(const Duck & duck)
   {
     ChangeType(TYPE_DUCK);
     reinterpret_cast<Duck*>(_data_ptr)[0] = duck;
   }
   void SetValueSoup(const Soup & soup)
   {
     ChangeType(TYPE_SOUP);
     reinterpret_cast<Soup*>(_data_ptr)[0] = soup;
   }

   template < class T >
   void set(T const & t)
   {
     ChangeType(type_enum_for< T >());
     reinterpret_cast< T * >(_data_ptr)[0] = t;
   }

   template < class T >
   T & get()
   {
     ChangeType(type_enum_for< T >());
     return reinterpret_cast< T * >(_data_ptr)[0];
   }

   template < class T >
   T const & get_const()
   {
     ChangeType(type_enum_for< T >());
     return reinterpret_cast< T const * >(_data_ptr)[0];
   }

private:
   void ChangeType(int newType);

   template <int S1, int S2> struct _maxx {enum {sz = (S1>S2)?S1:S2};};
   #define compile_time_max(a,b) (_maxx< (a), (b) >::sz)
   enum {STORAGE_SIZE = compile_time_max(sizeof(Duck), sizeof(Soup))};

   char _data[STORAGE_SIZE];
   int _type;   // a TYPE_* indicating what type of data we currently hold
   void * _data_ptr;
};

void DuckOrSoup :: ChangeType(int newType)
{
   if (newType != _type)
   {
      switch(_type)
      {
         case TYPE_DUCK: (reinterpret_cast<Duck*>(_data_ptr))->~Duck(); break;
         case TYPE_SOUP: (reinterpret_cast<Soup*>(_data_ptr))->~Soup(); break;
      }
      _type = newType;
      switch(_type)
      {
         case TYPE_DUCK: (void) new (_data) Duck();  break;
         case TYPE_SOUP: (void) new (_data) Soup();  break;
      }
   }
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   Duck sample_duck; sample_duck._speed = 23.23;
   Soup sample_soup; sample_soup._temperature = 98.6;
   std::cout << "Just saw sample constructors" << std::endl;
   {
     DuckOrSoup dos;
     std::cout << "Setting to Duck" << std::endl;
     dos.SetValueDuck(sample_duck);
     std::cout << "Setting to Soup" << std::endl;
     dos.SetValueSoup(sample_soup);
     std::cout << "Should see DuckOrSoup destruct which will dtor a Soup"
       << std::endl;
   }
   {
     std::cout << "Do it again with the templates" << std::endl;
     DuckOrSoup dos;
     std::cout << "Setting to Duck" << std::endl;
     dos.set(sample_duck);
     std::cout << "duck speed: " << dos.get_const<Duck>()._speed << std::endl;
     std::cout << "Setting to Soup" << std::endl;
     dos.set(sample_soup);
     std::cout << "soup temp: " << dos.get_const<Soup>()._temperature << std::endl;
     std::cout << "Should see DuckOrSoup destruct which will dtor a Soup"
       << std::endl;
   }
   {
     std::cout << "Do it again with only template get" << std::endl;
     DuckOrSoup dos;
     std::cout << "Setting to Duck" << std::endl;
     dos.get<Duck>() = Duck(42.42);
     std::cout << "duck speed: " << dos.get_const<Duck>()._speed << std::endl;
     std::cout << "Setting to Soup" << std::endl;
     dos.get<Soup>() = Soup(0, 32);
     std::cout << "soup temp: " << dos.get_const<Soup>()._temperature << std::endl;
     std::cout << "Should see DuckOrSoup destruct which will dtor a Soup"
       << std::endl;
   }
   std::cout << "Get ready to see sample destructors" << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: BTW, you can get rid of the default ctor when changing types through some overloading (and even more with more templates).  That way, you can directly copy construct or construct with parameters and save the initial default ctor overhead when switching types.

Comment: This does work, although it's not clear why I should need to store the extra void pointer, when I can recreate that void pointer "on the fly" as necessary.  It appears that the only reason for storing the void pointer as a member variable is to outwit the compiler's warning-generator, which isn't a very satisfying reason for incurring a per-item runtime penalty.

Answer (score 1):

I would have written the code like so:

```
typedef boost::variant<Duck, Soup> DuckOrSoup;
```

but I guess everyone got its own taste.

By the way, your code is buggy, you haven't taken care of possible alignment issues, you cannot just put an object at any point in the memory, there's a constraint to respect, which change with every type. In C++0x, there is the `alignof` keyword to get it, and a few other utilities to get aligned storage.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to convince GCC (4.2.4, run with `-Wstrict-aliasing=2`) not to complain by using a `void *` temporary, ie.

```
void SetValueDuck(const Duck & duck) {ChangeType(TYPE_DUCK); void *t=&_data; reinterpret_cast<Duck*>(t)[0] = duck;}
```

Comment: No luck, gcc 4.4.3 still warns with the above change (except now it warns about an anonymous pointer breaking the strict aliasing rules)

Answer (score 0):

I still cannot understand the need or usage for this but
g++ 4.4.3 with -O3 -Wall works with the following patch.
If it works, can you share the use case, why you need this?

```
class DuckOrSoup
{
public:
   DuckOrSoup() : _type(TYPE_UNSET) {_duck = NULL; _soup = NULL;/* empty*/}
   ~DuckOrSoup() {Unset();}

   void Unset() {ChangeType(TYPE_UNSET);}
   void SetValueDuck(const Duck & duck) {ChangeType(TYPE_DUCK); _duck = new (&_data[0])Duck (duck); }
   void SetValueSoup(const Soup & soup) { ChangeType(TYPE_SOUP); _soup = new (&_data[0])Soup (soup); }

private:
   void ChangeType(int newType);

   template <int S1, int S2> struct _maxx {enum {sz = (S1>S2)?S1:S2};};
   #define compile_time_max(a,b) (_maxx< (a), (b) >::sz)
   enum {STORAGE_SIZE = compile_time_max(sizeof(Duck), sizeof(Soup))};

   char _data[STORAGE_SIZE];
   int _type;   // a TYPE_* indicating what type of data we currently hold
   Duck* _duck;
   Soup* _soup;
};

void DuckOrSoup :: ChangeType(int newType)
{
   if (newType != _type)
   {
      switch(_type)
      {
         case TYPE_DUCK:
             _duck->~Duck();
             _duck = NULL;
             break;
         case TYPE_SOUP:
             _soup->~Soup();
             _soup = NULL;
             break;
      }
      _type = newType;
      switch(_type)
      {
         case TYPE_DUCK: _duck = new (&_data[0]) Duck();  break;
         case TYPE_SOUP: _soup = new (&_data[0]) Soup();  break;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why I need to store different kinds of data in a single object?  For the same reasons other people use boost::variant ... except that I don't want to make my program depend on boost.

Comment: The above code compiles without warnings, but it calls the object constructors twice (once in ChangeType() and again in SetValue*().  Also, it adds N extra pointer fields to each DuckOrSoup object, which uses up more memory (much more in my non-toy code, which supports more than two possible data types)